# Distribution build - "No such file or directory exists"

Tags: iphone

While creating an ad-hoc build in Xcode 4, I get an error "Operation couldn't be completed. No such file or direcotry exist" when I select Share in "Organizer - Archive" window. I have also included Entitlements.plist file, even status message also displays the build is successful.
I don't know what the problem is and where am I going wrong. Please suggest.

Answer (score 7):

After downloading XCode 4.3 beta with the IOS 5 SDK, the Organizer function to share and archive stopped working with a cryptic error "No such file or directory found".
It turns out that this is related to having two different versions of codesign_allocate . To fix the problem, do the following in a terminal window.

sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate /usr/bin

I've put this on my blog http://blog.dmahajan.net as well.

Comment: i tried the sudo stuff, the 'no such file...' error is still bugging me. any other tips for me?

Comment: make a copy of or rename the codesign_allocate in /usr/bin/, delete the original then run EasyCoder's command and it should work.

Comment: This was exactly my problem and following these instructions worked perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Did you sign the archived version with your Ad-Hoc profile, if so then select "don't Re-sign" in the share screen drop down.

Comment: Yes. I did that. I tried again but the same error appears. Couldn't figure out this problem.

Comment: Resolved this problem. Choose Products -> Build for -> Build for Archiving. After that under Products in project tree, open the app in finder.

Comment: SamG, i m still facing exactly the same error as ur original problem. How did u solve the problem exactly? thanks!

Comment: dunforget, please look at the answer below. I found that this problem was occuring when I was developing application in Xcode version < 4, and creating builds in xcode 4.

Answer (score 1):

Guys,
Another thing I found is that if you've developed an app in xcode < xcode4  and you are creating builds in xcode4 then you might get this error.

To resolve this, follow these steps-
1. In Entitlements.plist, add a key- "application-identifier", type- "String", value - "$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)"

1. Now create an "Archive" build, when the window appears, right click on the app name and "Show in finder".
2. AppName -> Right Click -> Show Package Contents.
3. Products -> .app file. Now use this .app file along with the provisioning profile.

This solution worked for me very well.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: duplicated keys in your keychain. Solved my problem.